# a nice integral

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-1}^{1} (x^{2n+1} + \frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}) \ln (1+e^{xn})dx.$$

Let:

$$ I= \int_{-1}^{1} (x^{2n+1} + \frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}) \ln (1+e^{xn})dx.$$

By King's Rule:

$$ I=- \int_{-1}^{1} (x^{2n+1} + \frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}) \ln (1+e^{-xn})dx.$$

On adding the above two integrals,

$$ 2I=n \int_{-1}^{1} (x^{2n+2} + \frac{1}{x^{2n}}) dx.$$

Then, I stuck. Any help?

Comment: How are you stuck exactly? Seems like the integral for $2I$ is just a simple application of the power rule.

Comment: It happens, I don't know, I need a help

Comment: Well ... there's your help then? Try the power rule and you should have no trouble evaluating the integral, and you can take half and find the limit.

Comment: I tried, it seems a strange solution

Comment: @George, why don't you add to your question details what you did using the Power Rule.  Show the strange solution and how you got it.

Comment: I found $$ 2I=n [ \frac{(-1)^{2n}+1}{2n+3} + \frac{1+(-1)^{-2n}}{1-2n}]$$ but i can't move then

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a singularity at $x = 0$ in the integrand.  So the integral doesn't converge for any real-valued $n$.  A Cauchy principal value may exist.